# Bring window into focus / Activate window on Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to work Cypress into my workflow, developing frontend web applications. But I find it annoying that I have to press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> every time I have to open it. Slow and tedious!

Cypress opens two windows:

1. A version of Chrome, that Cypress controls. I *have* found a way to bring that to the front, using [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) (launch application). This solves 70% of my problem.
2. A Cypress-window, where one can choose which tests to run.

I still would like to easily bring the Cypress-window into focus, so I faster can choose which group of tests to run.

Cypress is an ElectronJS-application that is in the `node_modules` for each given project I'm working on. This means that I can't make a shortcut to an application in the applications-folder, since it's a different app that needs to be opened, depending on which project I'm working on. I can't open it using Spotlight either (for the same reasons).

Does anyone know a way, how I can set it up, so I can press a shortcut-combination to open Cypress (or bring it to the front of my windows)?

I'm on macOS Mojave v. 10.14.5

Comment: Lock them both to the same Space. Set a key command to switch to that Space.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. But I'm not using Spaces, - so this would be the only use I have of it. But it's one way to do it.

Comment: I *live by Spaces*. It's the single most efficient workflow tool Apple ever invented :) It's far more use than the abysmally implemented Fullscreen. I've done a couple of answers on it over on Ask Different - this was the first one I found - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275